# I've implemented a video tag inside of a modal. On click of it the video should play. But, in my case, the same video is playing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm new to React and trying to create a video library. Everything is working fine but I'm not not able to render the video in a dynamic way. Even if what I have implemented is dynamic, but it's playing the same video.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(cors());



   app.get('/latestVideos', (req, res) => {
  res.send({
   "videos": [
    {
        "thumbnail":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/R-9i5NJsiL0/maxresdefault.jpg",
        "source": "http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/media/car-20120827-85.mp4",
        "title": "Lambhorghini",
        "channelName":"Auto Car",
        "views":"7 million views",
        "lastUpdated":"3 weeks ago"
    },
    {


      "thumbnail":"https://theawesomer.com/photos/2016/09/n6pdwdmjkze.jpg",
        "source": "http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/media/motion-20120802-85.mp4",
        "title": "Porche",
        "channelName":"LoudWire",
        "views":"1 million views",
        "lastUpdated":"4 weeks ago"
    },
    {
        "thumbnail":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bsSK1DccV_Y/maxresdefault.jpg",
        "source": "http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/media/oops-20120802-85.mp4",
        "title": "Havana",
        "channelName":"Camila Cabello",
        "views":"7 million views",
        "lastUpdated":"6 weeks ago"
    },
    {
        "thumbnail":"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6njcfy1wTsPr8WAs5CubtCommlw2HAfYFIp1IY2yWRU2Oj1uM4A",
        "source": "http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/media/car-20120827-85.mp4",
        "title": "See You Again",
        "channelName":"Charlie Puth",
        "views":"3 million views",
        "lastUpdated":"1 week ago"
    },
    {
        "thumbnail":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Z0P9KW9B7nw/maxresdefault.jpg",
        "source": "http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/media/motion-20120802-85.mp4",
        "title": "Manali To Leh",
        "channelName":"Mumbiker Nikhil",
        "views":"5 million views",
        "lastUpdated":"2 weeks ago"
    },
    {
        "thumbnail":"https://mm.aiircdn.com/5/679578.jpg",
        "source": "http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/media/oops-20120802-85.mp4",
        "title": "Don't Talk To Strangers",
        "channelName":"Ronnie James Dio",
        "views":"1 million views",
        "lastUpdated":"4 weeks ago"
    }

]
  });
     });




app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

latestVideos.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
 import {connect} from 'react-redux';
 import {latestVideos} from "../../actions";



   class LatestVideos extends Component {

      componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getLatestVideos();
    }
      render() {

     const {latestVideos} = this.props;
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h4 className="mt-3 mb-3"><i className="fas fa-play mr-2"></i>Latest Videos</h4>
            <div className="row">
                {latestVideos && latestVideos.map((data, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={i} className="col-sm-4">

                            <div className="card mb-3">


                                <img className="card-img-top" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" src={data.thumbnail}></img>

                                <div className="modal fade" id="myModal">
                                    <div className="modal-dialog">
                                        <div className="modal-content">
                                            <div className="modal-body">
                                                <video src={data.source} id="video"
                                                    poster="//shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/assets/poster.jpg"
                                                    controls  muted  autoPlay>
                                                </video>
                                                {console.log(data.s)}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h5 className="card-title">{data.title}</h5>
                                    <p className="card-text">{data.channelName}</p>
                                    <p>{data.views} | {data.lastUpdated}</p>
                                </div>


                            </div>


                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
     }
    }

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    latestVideos: state.videoBrowseList.latestVideos,
}
};

 const mapActionsToProps = dispatch => {
return bindActionCreators({
    getLatestVideos: latestVideos
}, dispatch);
 };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(LatestVideos);
```

As you can from my code that is in server.js, everything is dynamic and in the frontend I have used map function. Everything is rendering, only the video, is playing the same video over and over again. Can someone please help me to troubleshoot this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your id `myModal` is same for all modal window, so only the first modal will be opened always, `id` should be unique.

Try the below code

```
<img className="card-img-top" data-toggle="modal" data-target={"#myModal" + i} src={data.thumbnail}></img>

<div className="modal fade" id={"myModal" + i}>
    <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-body">
                <video src={data.source} id={"video" + i} poster="//shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/assets/poster.jpg"
                    controls muted autoPlay>
                </video>
                {console.log(data.s)}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```